# How to convert to ObjectId and match dates on MongoDB lookup?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am grabbing an id from a nested value in a schema, then using that to lookup the id from another table and also matching on a couple dates from that table. I've tried a regular match/lookup/unwind/match and also a lookup/let/pipeline technique. In both cases, it ignores matching on the date for some reason. What am I missing?

Here is one method for reference. I'm not sure where to put the sort either since it doesn't seem to pull $meeting out to sort on.

**EXAMPLE RECORDS**

```
PRODUCT
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5f36c0df6d5553e6af208cac"),
"items" : [
    {
        "paramType" : "Meeting", 
        "paramValue" : "5f36c0df6d5553e6af208cab"
    }
], 
"ownerId" : ObjectId("12345678901234567")
}

MEETING
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5f36c0df6d5553e6af208cab"), 
"startDate" : ISODate("2020-08-18T10:00:00.000+0000"), 
"endDate" : ISODate("2020-08-18T11:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

**AGGREGATE**

```
db.getCollection("products").aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
          "ownerId": ObjectId("12345678901234567")
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$items"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "meetings",
              let: { "meetingId": '$items.paramValue' },
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $match: {
                    $expr: {
                      $and: [
                        { $eq: ["$_id", "$$meetingId"] },
                        {
                          $eq: ["meeting.startDate", {
                            "$gte": ["$meeting.startDate", ISODate("2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z")]
                          }]
                        },
                        {
                          $eq: ["meeting.endDate", {
                            "$lte": ["$meeting.endDate", ISODate("2020-08-31T23:59:59.999Z")]
                          }]
                        }
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
            as: "meeting"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$meeting"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 1,
            "items": 1,
            "meeting": "$meeting"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            'meeting.startDate': 1
        }
    },

]
```

);

It might be because `item.paramValue` is not converted to an ObjectId before the lookup. But can't figure out how to convert it inside an aggregate. I tried this, but no go

```
{
$addFields: {
"convertedMeetingId": { $toObjectId: "$items.paramValue" }
}}

let: { "meetingId": "$convertedMeetingId" }
```

Comment: So your question is about type conversion? Remove everything to do with joins ($lookup etc.) and leave only type conversion-relevant bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quick fixes in `$lookup` other looks good,

- `let` you can convert `meetingId` string to `ObjectId` here using `$toObjectId`
- `$gte` and `$lte`, you used `$meeting.startDate` and `$meeting.endDate` it should be `$startDate` and `$endDate` because you are already inside `meeting` lookup.
- i am not sure why you have used $eq and with `$gte` and `$lte`, if i am not wrong i have corrected and removed $eq it will work directly.

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "meetings",
      let: { meetingId: { $toObjectId: "$items.paramValue" } },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$_id", "$$meetingId"] },
                { $gte: ["$startDate", ISODate("2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z")] },
                { $lte: ["$endDate", ISODate("2020-08-31T23:59:59.999Z")] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "meeting"
    }
  },
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XOzAPz9f4fz)

Comment: Works great! Thanks!